# no matching function call for selection sort function with templates(C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, selection, template-argument-deduction

I'm playing around with templates and I was wondering why I'm getting a no matching function error using templates.

```
/*selection sort*/
template <typename InputIterator, typename T>
void selection_sort(InputIterator first, InputIterator last){
    InputIterator min;
    for(; first != last - 1; ++first){
        min = first;

        for(T i = (first + 1); i != last ; ++i)
        {
            if(*first < *min)
                min = i;
        }
        myswap(*first, *min);
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    vector<int> v(a, a+10);
    selection_sort(v.begin(),v.end());
}
```

Comment: Also note, you don't need to copy that thing in to a vector if you're using C++11; just go with the answer you marked (rhalbersma's) and use `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)` as the first and last iterators. the  rest will take care of itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an undeduced template parameter T, so you need 1) move your `typename T` as the first template parameter:

```
// now InputIterator will be deduced
template <typename T, typename InputIterator>
void selection_sort(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    // your implementation
}
```

and 2) to qualify your call to sort as `selection_sort<int>(v.begin(), v.end());`

BTW, here's a somwhat more generic implementation of selection sort, note it takes only an iterator and comparison function as template parameters, with the comparison function taking the value type that the iterator points to (this is C++11 code because of the default function template parameter, for C++98 compilers you need to have 2 overloads, with or without the comparison function)

```
template< typename ForwardIterator, typename Compare = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type> >
void selection_sort(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Compare cmp = Compare())
{
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
                auto const selection = std::min_element(it, last, cmp);
                std::iter_swap(selection, it);
        }
}
```

The call to `std::min_element` is equivalent to your for loop, and the `iter_swap` is equal to your own swap. The advantage of using STL algorithms is that they are much more likely to be correct (off-by-one errors in handwritten code are very common)

PS: you can similarly write an insertion_sort algorithm in 2 lines using `std::upper_bound` and `std::rotate` ([exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578502/819272) for the reader)

Comment: +1 for the wonderful goo known as `iterator_traits`. *love* that class.

Comment: @WhozCraig after being burned too many times writing `ForwardIterator::value_type` and trying to pass a regular pointer to that, I learned to love that class as well ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `typename T` which seems not to be used, can't be deduced by the compiler. You will have to specify the types explicitly:

```
selection_sort<vector<int>::iterator, int>(v.begin(),v.end());
```

Comment: even the iterator type cannot be deduced because it is not the last template parameter