# Insertion sort c++ vectors

Tags: c++

```
void insertion_sort(int *data, unsigned int n) {
    for (unsigned int uns = 1; uns < n; ++uns ) {
        int next = data[uns];

        unsigned int idx;
        for (idx = uns; idx > 0 && data[idx - 1] > next; --idx) {
            data[idx] = data[idx - 1];
        }
        data[idx] = next;   
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<Person> crew= ucitaj_osobe("osobe.txt"); /*this reads the file osobe.tx and stores it in vector crew,this works */

       Person o;


    insertion_sort(polje, 100); // ???
    ispisi_osobe(popis); /* this prints out the vector,this works too*/

    return 0;
}
```

how do I send this vector to insertion sort,and sort it? 
please help,the code for insertion sort was implemented from another source

Comment: Not necessarily insertion sort, but `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());`.

Comment: Ehm... your insertion sort works on integers, but you're trying to sort a vector of Person? Or what is polje? If you're going to write it yourself, why not make it work on a vector instead?

Comment: @H2CO3 Guaranteed not to be insertion sort.  But still: why not `std::sort`?

Comment: see for a generic insertion sort http://stackoverflow.com/a/14578502/819272

Answer (score 2):

Your function `insertion_sort` is implemented to sort arrays of `int` and the function will not work for sorting of your vector of `Person` objects.

If you want to sort your vector of `Person` objects I suggest you use `std::sort` from the standard library. To use it you must implement the `<` operator for `Person` objects.

**Example:**

```
// Only to demonstrate.
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

// Implement according to your needs.
bool operator< (const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs) {
    return lhs.name < rhs.name;
}
```

```
int main() {
    vector<Person> crew = ucitaj_osobe("osobe.txt");

    std::sort(begin(crew), end(crew));

    ispisi_osobe(popis);

    // return 0; Unnecessary in main function.
}
```

**Live example:** http://ideone.com/YEL7IV

Note that `std::sort` is not guaranteed to use insertion sort.

Comment: Even if `Person` will convert implicitly to `int`, an array of `Person` cannot be used where an array of `int` is expected.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, I figured as much. Removed that part from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a pointer to the array within a vector by passing the address of the first element within the vector.

insertion_sort(&crew[0], crew.size());

Comment: As written `insertion_sort()` takes an `int *` and size, not a `Person *` and size. Thus, this answer will not work unless (a) `sizeof(Person) == sizeof(int)` and (b) `class Person` has but-one member, an `int`, and even then you may fall prey to structure packing and/or are significantly obfuscating what is really going on. Either way, it is very likely the approach in this answer will NOT work.

Comment: True, I didn't pay enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insertion_sort` is designed to sort arrays of `int`, and
only arrays of `int`.  You cannot use it on arrays of `Person`.

You don't say why you want to use this insertion sort, instead
of `std::sort`.  But if you want to use it on vector of
`Person`, you'll have to change its first argument to `Person*`,
and pass it `&crew[0], crew.size()`.  A better solution would be
to convert it to take an `std::vector<Person>` directly, rather
than a pointer and a size.  An even better solution would be
a template taking two bidirectional iterators, and invoke it
with `crew.begin(), crew.end()`.

Comment: NB if the vector contains `Person` objects instead of pointers, the sort will have perform copy construction and/or assignment operations on `Person` objects whenever it wants to move them around. This may or may not be important for performance, depending on how complex a `Person` is (some people can be very complex).

Comment: @DanielEarwicker If the profiler says that there is a blocking point later, then that's something that we might look at.  Given that he's using an insertion sort, rather than `std::sort`, one has to assume that performance isn't an issue here (and that the size of the array isn't too large, because otherwise, it would be an issue).

Comment: I absolutely agree about measuring first.