# selection sort algorithm using vectors

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, selection-sort

I am trying to get the selection sort to work with vectors. I run the program and it does the first part unsorted but then says Expression: vector subscript out of range. Can't figure out what is causing it.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 

template<typename Comparable> 
void selectionSort(vector<Comparable> & toSort) 
{
    int pos, min, i;

    for( pos = 0; pos < 30; ++pos)
    {
        min = toSort[pos];

        for( i = toSort[pos + 1]; i < toSort[30]; ++i)
        {   
            if( i < min)
            {
                min = i;
            }
        }

        if( min != pos)
        {   
            std::swap(toSort.at(min), toSort.at(pos));

        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{ 
    const int NUM_ITEMS = 5; 
    int array[NUM_ITEMS] = { 16, 271, 77, 40, 120 }; 
    vector<int> sortingVector; 


    for(int i=0;i<NUM_ITEMS;i++) { 
        sortingVector.push_back(array[i]); 
    } 

    cout << "Before sort \n"; 

    for(int i=0;i<NUM_ITEMS;i++) { 
        cout << sortingVector[i] << "\n"; 
    } 

    selectionSort(sortingVector); 

    cout << "After sort \n"; 

    for(int i=0;i<NUM_ITEMS;i++) { 
        cout << sortingVector[i] << "\n"; 
    } 
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your vector is size 5 and you are treating it as if it were size 31.

Comment: Are you saying you didn't see this? `for( pos = 0; pos < 30; ++pos)`, and then you are accessing `tosort[30]`?

Comment: see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14412866/819272) for a STL-style `selection_sort` using iterators

Comment: umm i dont know how i put 30 in there. i feel like an idiot. thanks for pointing my dumb mishap

Comment: SO Good question: "What does compiler/runtime mean when it says X?"
SO Good question: "Why does this (very very short; ie 10 lines or fewer) crafted-for-SO example of code generate error X?"
SO Bad question: "I'm getting runtime error X in this mess of code, please debug it for me"

Comment: Why in the world are you hard-coding the size instead of using `toSort.size()`?

Comment: blastfurnace. I guess I am brand new to this and yes size would make more sense.

Comment: I rolled back to the original version. You were changing the question completely by fixing the loop, and making the answers obsolete.

Comment: okay, i was just trying to fix it so i wouldnt get duplicate answers. but i guess it makes sense if everyone reads the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody knows what this magic number 30 means in your function

```
template<typename Comparable> 
void selectionSort(vector<Comparable> & toSort) 
{
    int pos, min, i;

    for( pos = 0; pos < 30; ++pos)
    {
        min = toSort[pos];

        for( i = toSort[pos + 1]; i < toSort[30]; ++i)
```

and even the function itself does not know what this magic number 30 means.

If you are using standard container `std::vector` then it has member function `size` that can always report how many elements there are in the container.

In any case if you will use size() instead of 30 the code is invalid because the inner loop will access the element with the position equal to size()

for( i = **toSort[pos + 1]**; i < **toSort[30]**; ++i)

I think there should be

```
for( i = pos + 1; i < toSor.size(); ++i)
```

This condition

```
if( min != pos)
```

is also invalid because you are comparing different entities.

The function could be defined the following way

```
template<typename Comparable> 
void selectionSort( std::vector<Comparable> & toSort ) 
{
    for ( std::vector<Comparable>::size_type pos = 0; pos < toSort.size(); ++pos )
    {
        std::vector<Comparable>::size_type min = pos;

        for ( std::vector<Comparable>::size_type i = pos + 1; i < toSort.size(); ++i )
        {   
            if ( toSort[i] < toSort[min] ) min = i;
        }

        if ( min != pos )
        {   
            std::swap( toSort[min], toSort[pos] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i switched it to 5 like it should be. I dont know where i got the 30 from..but I still get an error

Comment: @user3424390: Did you know that a `std::vector` knows how many elements it contains? Use `toSort.size()`.

Comment: what makes min != pos) invalid? do i just need to get rid of everything after that or replace it with something? sorry ima noob at this

Comment: @user3424390 pos is an index while min is a value at some other index. See my uodated post anew.

Comment: oh wow. that makes absolute sense. I need to dig much deeper in learning these things. That helped! Thanks so much to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
for( pos = 0; pos < 30; ++pos)
{
    min = toSort[pos];
```

if you have to do it in this specific way then consider using `NUM_ITEMS` as a range check inside your sorting function instead of taking 0 to 29.

```
for( i = toSort[pos + 1]; i < toSort[30]; ++i)
{
```

You are accessing element 30 here directly although the vector only has 5 elements. Be sure to check for `pos + 1` as this may result in errors later on.